# Spring Data Neo4j - can't get result from custom query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I wrote below code to retrieve class entities.

```java
@Repository
public interface ClassRepository extends ReactiveNeo4jRepository<Class, Long> {
    @Query("MATCH (project: Project) WHERE $pid in project.pids " +
            "MATCH (c: Class {name: $name})-[:relates*1..$depth]-(target: Class) " +
            "RETURN target")
    Flux<Class> findClassByName(@Param("name") String name, Long pid, @Param("depth") Long depth);
}
```

And Class entity is this.

```java
@Node("Class")
@ToString
@Getter
@Setter
public class Class {
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String url;
    private String name;
    private Boolean isAbstract;
    private Boolean isStatic;

    @Relationship(type="belongs_to_package", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Package aPackage;

    @Relationship(type = "relates", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<ClassRelationship> classRelates = new HashSet<>();
    @Relationship(type = "relates", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<InterfaceRelationship> interfaceRelates = new HashSet<>();
    @Relationship(type = "nested", direction = Relationship.Direction.INCOMING)
    private Set<Class> nested = new HashSet<>();

    public Class(String url, String name, Boolean isAbstract, Boolean isStatic, Package aPackage) {
        this.url = url;
        this.name = name;
        this.isAbstract = isAbstract;
        this.isStatic = isStatic;
        this.aPackage = aPackage;
    }
}
```

But it generates error like this...

```
org.neo4j.driver.exceptions.ClientException: Parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns (use a literal map instead, eg. "{id: {param}.id}") (line 1, column 97 (offset: 96))
"MATCH (project: Project) WHERE $pid in project.pids MATCH (c: Class {name: $name})-[:relates*1..$depth]-(target: Class) RETURN target"
```

When I change [:relates*1..$depth] to [:relates], it doesn't generate any errors. So I know where the error is generated but I can't know why the error is generated..
What can I do for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using parameters as boundary/limit value is not allowed in Cypher. (https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/)

I would advise to use the `Neo4jTemplate` here.
More specific something around `Neo4jTemplate#findAll(Statement statement, Class<T> domainType)`.
This method let's you define your own query, created manually e.g. by the Cypher-DSL (https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/cypher-dsl/) to avoid security problems due to injection.

Something else you *could* do is to use the `Neo4jClient`, create the query manually, e.g. with the Cypher-DSL again, and use the existing mapping function for your `Project` entity (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#neo4j-client.result-objects.mapping-functions)

In short, something like this (without the Cypher-DSL part):

```
BiFunction<TypeSystem, MapAccessor, Movie> mappingFunction = neo4jMappingContext.getRequiredMappingFunctionFor(Project.class);
Project project = client
    .query("<your statement>")
    .fetchAs(Project.class).mappedBy((TypeSystem t, Record record) -> {
       return record.get("target")
            .asList(project -> mappingFunction.apply(t, project));
    })
    .one();
```